# jQuery delay/disable overlay on hover

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a simple thumbnail overlay script:

```
    // Hover thumbnail overlay
    $('li.carouselBlock a').hover( function () {
        // Display the overlay
        $(this).find('span.carousel-description').stop( false, true ).delay(500).animate( {'top':'0px'}, 500 ).show();
    },
    function () {
        // Hide the overlay
        $(this).find('span.carousel-description').stop( false, true ).animate( {'top':'-100px'}, 500 );
    });
```

I'd like it so if the user glances their mouse over the thumbnail (or off it in fact) the JS doesn't kick in unless the hover has been consistent for around half a second.

Initially I thought this could be solved with jQuery's `.delay()` method like the other answers I've come across, but then I discovered this will only "delay" the animation (it *always* kicks in even if the user glances across it) rather than prevent it from kicking in unless the user has hovered for a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be most easily solved using the jQuery hoverIntent plugin:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Simply replacing calls to jQuery's "hover" method with "hoverIntent" does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

What you do here, is set and reset a timer. The important part here is to reset the timer on mouse-out to ensure it doesn't fire under that condition.

```
var timer1
    // Hover thumbnail overlay
    $('li.carouselBlock a').hover( function () {
        // Display the overlay
        timer1= setTimeout(function(){ //set on mouse over
            $(this).find('span.carousel-description').stop( false, true ).animate(    {'top':'0px'}, 500 ).show();
            }
    },500),
    function () {
        // Hide the overlay
        clearTimeout(timer1) //reset on mouse out
        $(this).find('span.carousel-description').stop( false, true ).animate( {'top':'-100px'}, 500 );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. Since I posted this question I came across the "hoverIntent" plugin (http://goo.gl/LDZdQ) which seems to work very well. Would you recommend your solution over this?

Comment: In most cases, I prefer my own code. If it breaks, I can fix it. If I need to change something, I know how it works. For complex cross-browser stuff, I leave it up to plugins and frameworks.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's my question really, would you not consider this functionality (attempting to determine the "intent" of the user) complex enough to warrant a plugin like hoverIntent? If your code above provides all the same functionality I can't imagine why hoverIntent exists!

Comment: Interestingly that code you provided didn't seem to function. No console error either.

Comment: Without your HTML it's hard to tell why.

Answer (score 1):

Try javascripts' native `setTimeout` instead:

```
var timeout;

// Hover thumbnail overlay
$('li.carouselBlock a').hover( function () {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find('span.carousel-description')
            .stop(false, true)
            .animate( {'top':'0px'}, 500 )
            .show();
    }, 500); // 500ms
},
function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).find('span.carousel-description').stop( false, true ).animate( {'top':'-100px'}, 500 );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. Since I posted this question I came across the "hoverIntent" plugin (http://goo.gl/LDZdQ) which seems to work very well. Would you recommend your solution over this?

Comment: Interestingly that code you provided didn't seem to function. No console error either.